# Concatenate the count number with a duplicate text pattern using python ReGex

Tags: python, regex

I have very large text file. It contains duplicate text patterns. In the code below, we can see the pattern "Path": "/home/downloads/file" exists 3 times. I want to add/concat the count number at the end of each Path pattern according to its position. E.g. when the code finds first Path pattern, it should concatenate 1 at the end like "Path": "/home/downloads/file/1". For the second Path pattern, it should add 2 at the end e.g.
"Path": "/home/downloads/file/2" and so on. My current code counts the patterns but doesn't concatenate it properly at the end of the Path pattern. Below is my code, its current output and the desired output. I've also added a small chunk from the text.

```
from io import StringIO  
import re


file = StringIO("""{
    "title": "Pilot",
    "image": [
        {
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file"
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file",
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file"
        }
    ],
    "content": "<p>The wing man ...</p>"
}""")

text = file.read()
patterns = r'"Path": "(.*?)"'

count = 0

for match in re.finditer(patterns, text):
   count += 1
   replace = '"Path": "\\1/' + str(count) + '"'
   text = re.sub(patterns, replace, text)

print(text)
```

Current output of the code is:

```
{
    "title": "Pilot",
    "image": [
        {
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file/1/2/3"
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file/1/2/3",
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file/1/2/3"
        }
    ],
    "content": "<p>The wing man ...</p>"
}
```

Desired output is:

```
{
    "title": "Pilot",
    "image": [
        {
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file/1"
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file/2",
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file/3"
        }
    ],
    "content": "<p>The wing man ...</p>"
}
```

Comment: Your example string looks strange (missing commas, duplicate keys) since it is probably a json string (in real life). So, use a json parser, and provide a more realistic example.

Comment: Yes, looks like a json file. [Parse](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-json-file-using-python/) it directly as a python dict and access the values by key.

Comment: I agree with all the above comments. It looks like a bad JSON data. However, I have to deal it as a text, which is the requirement of my task. If we deal it as text, the JSON parsing, commas, formatting becomes irrelevant.

Comment: After adding the missing comma reported by @Casimir, it's a valid JSON string and parses (in Ruby) to `{"title"=>"Pilot", "image"=>[{"Path"=>"/home/downloads/file"}], "content"=>"<p>The wing man ...</p>"}`. As the inner hash has multiple duplicate keys, `"Path"` (also reported by Casimir), only the last key-value pair is kept. Therefore if you modify the string as you want to do, and then parse it as a JSON string, `[{"Path"=>"/home/downloads/file"}]` becomes `[{"Path"=>"/home/downloads/file/3"}]`, which is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to limit the times that `re.sub` makes the replacement:

```
for cnt,match in enumerate(re.finditer(patterns, text),1):
    text = re.sub(patterns, rf'\1/{cnt}', text, count=1)
```

But as others have said, you **should** use JSON tools to work with JSON -- not regex.

Here is a simple example:

```
import json 
data=json.loads(file.read())
k,v=data["image"][0].popitem()
data["image"]=[]
for i in range(1,4):
    data["image"].append(f"{v}/{i}")

>>> print(json.dumps(data,sort_keys=True, indent=4))
{
    "content": "<p>The wing man ...</p>",
    "image": [
        "/home/downloads/file/1",
        "/home/downloads/file/2",
        "/home/downloads/file/3"
    ],
    "title": "Pilot"
}
```

Comment: The data I use has a very complex structure. The example I used here is very small and unreal but serves the purpose. On my actual data, I did it with JSON parsing, but my code became too tedious. To keep the code concise, and try a different way, I had to deal the data as sequence of characters. Hence ReGex was the optimal choice for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use re.sub with a function to replace non-overlapping occurences as follows.

**Code**

```
text = file.read()
patterns = r'"Path": "(.*?)"'

def repl(m):
    global count
    count += 1                                         # update count with each 
                                                       # detection of pattern
    return m.group(0).replace('file', f'file/{count}') # Desired substitution

count = 0
text = re.sub(patterns, repl, text)  # applies function repl to each detection of pattern

print(text)
```

**Output**

```
{
    "title": "Pilot",
    "image": [
        {
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file/1"
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file/2",
            "Path": "/home/downloads/file/3"
        }
    ],
    "content": "<p>The wing man ...</p>"
}
```